# xcode save image to a specific file in library

Tags: ios, xcode6, assets, photos

I would like to save an image to the Assets library with a specific name. Or to the Photos library. I think it's the same thing. I would like to be able to save the file like "file1.png". So far I tried with `writeToFile` method but I couldn't get the path right.

Comment: please be more specific because you question is not clear, do you want save the image in camera roll photos or documents directory

Comment: @Aladin I agree. And please show what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
       NSString  *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"]; // identity the home directory and file name

      [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

       NSString *imageFile = [@"file://" stringByAppendingString:path];
       NSLog(@"----imageFile path--%@",imageFile);
```